# Why does GNOME have to be removed for PHP 7 on Debian 8 (Jessie)?

Tags: linux, debian, php, upgrade, debian-jessie

Just [upgraded](http://www.linuxveda.com/2015/04/28/upgrade-from-debian-7-to-debian-8/) my VirtualBox VM's OS from Debian 7 (Wheezy) to Debian 8 (Jessie) and want to PHP from 5.5.x to 7.0.2. The simpliest solution seems to do this via the Synaptic Package Manager. So I added

```
deb http://packages.dotdeb.org jessie all
deb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org jessie all
```

to the `/etc/apt/sources.list`, performed `apt-get update`, opened the Synaptic GUI. The search by "php7" returns a list of PHP 7 packages. OK. But when I want to mark one, e.g. php7.0 for installation and see the list of the affected packages, I find a lot of packages, that would be removed, e.g. `gnome`!

[[image]

I've already tried it out. After this I've lost the OS GUI and even coulnd not reinstall it (and was happy to have a snapshot created before the experiments with PHP 7).

What is the problem here and how to solve/avoid it?